# single point of failure in IIS Web Farm Framework setting?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, iis-7.5, web-farm

ASP.NET WEB API
Windows Server 2008 R2/IIS 7.5/Web Farm Framework 2.5

I am planning to deploy application across 4 web servers.

Should i use shared content/configuration using DFS among web servers for web farm scenario?

Second option is to use Web Farm Framework for deployment.

Furthermore, is there chance of single point of failure in WFF? for example what if primary server goes down.

which option would be better? pros and cons of each of the above.

I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Farm Framework is easy.  The only SPOF exists when integrating with an external load balancer as opposed to using the built in Application Request Routing.  This is mainly because unless your load balancer is able to detect a failure on the server it may still try to route to that server.

If you are just deploying a single application the WFF is a perfect choice and MUCH easier to configure than the traditional shared config setup.